# How to count the number of friday's between two dates in Excel? (but only if it spans Friday midnight!)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've seen a number of Excel formulas which can count the number of fridays between two dates.  However, they don't work 100% for me, because I'm only wanting to count the number of friday's which go past midnight.

And by 'midnight', I mean the last minute/second of the day, so 23:59:59.

**For example:**

**Start**: Friday, 21st June 2019, 7pm

**End**: Monday, 24th June, 3am

That would span "1" friday at midnight

However, this next example would not span any, since it does not go past Friday 23:59:59;

**Start**: Monday, 17th June, 3am

**End**: Friday, 21st June 2019, 7pm

Comment: For me Formula works properly, could you edit the post & include the formula you have tried so far!!

Comment: Suppose it starts Friday July 12 23:59:59 and ends Saturday July 13 00:00:01. Is that 2-second period a count of 1? i.e., are you asking to count occurrences of Friday 23:59:59 rather than any actual period or minimum time during Friday?

Comment: @RajeshS what formula works correctly?

Comment: @fixer1234, in my use case, there may be a minimum time, but I'm not sure what it is. For now, I think any range that covers Friday 23:59:59 should count as '1', even if it's only 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take on a reliable, understandable way to do this is to just count the full Fridays.  Any Friday followed by another day in the date range must span midnight.  The only way Friday cannot span midnight is if the end date is a Friday (if it is still Friday, it hasn't passed midnight).

[image]

So if the start date is in A2 and end date is in B2, my solution would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(INT(A2)&":"&INT(B2))))=6))-(WEEKDAY(B2)=6)
```

This creates a range of imaginary rows whose row numbers are the date numbers using INDIRECT (this requires integer dates).  SUMPRODUCT counts the number of Fridays.

This will include the end date if it is a Friday.  Testing the end date to see if it is a Friday returns `1` if true, `0` otherwise.  That result is subtracted from the count.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below, it will count fridays that turn past midnight into saturdays between start and end dates.

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=IF(INT((WEEKDAY(A2-6)-A2+B2)/7)>0,INT((WEEKDAY(A2-7)-A2+B2)/7),0)
```

Drag down

Comment: @fixer1234, yes thanks. I must say I have also been thinking about using the row references with `INDIRECT` but wouldn't that be volatille?

Comment: True, plus doing an array calculation isn't the fastest way, either.  The OP didn't indicate that this would be a massive amount of data, or that processing efficiency was important for this application, so I didn't worry about it.  But you're right, if that's important, a calculation approach like your answer would be faster.